# Photoshop CS6 - Can't find Show -> Pixel Grid

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, grids

I can't find the Pixel Grid option like I would have in CS5. I just upgraded. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

`View > Show > Show Pixel Grid`

Note: The pixel grid is only visible when zoomed in on any document. You won't see it at 100% in most cases.

[image: menu]

Another possibility, brought up by Lèse majesté, is OpenGL preferences. Do you have a video card which meets the minimum system requirements? If you view `Preferences > Performance`, under Graphic Processor Settings, are those enabled?

Comment: It's very unlikely that this is due to a fowled up installation. It's more likely he just doesn't have OpenGL/GPU-acceleration enabled.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem when I plugged in my external monitor. Restarting Photoshop fixed the missing <kbd>Show Pixel Grid</kbd> menu item.

Answer (score 2):

Go into `Edit > Preferences > Guides, Grid, Slices`... Then change some things in `Grid`, like Gridlines every {number} **pixels**

Comment: How does this solve the problem? Does the pixel grid option come back in the menu?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and what fixed it for me was going into <kbd>Edit > Preferences > Performance</kbd> and then changing my `cache levels` from 4 to 6, then simply restart.

Now i have the pixel grid option where as before I didn't. Happy PhotoShopping!

Comment: Hi Theo, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl+H and it shall be solved. May be a few amenities re hidden by chance. I dont understand why I have to write such a long sentence when my answer ended in the first sentence. Strange criteria.

Answer (score -1):

Click on `Show Extras Options` at the bottom of the tab, then check the Pixel Grid box.